# Interpreting bank's calculation of interest: gross, net, and what the bank pays

Tags: united-states, income-tax, investing, banking, calculation

I cannot understand how my bank calculates the interest. Here is what the system shows when I invest 175,000 pesos (it's small money in dollars):

```
Investment instrument: PAYMENT AT MATURITY
Investment amount: $ 175,000.00
Term: 1 Days
Gross Interest to Earn: $ 20.66
Total tax: $ 20.8
Net interest to earn: $ 41.18
Net amount to maturity: $ 175,013.73
```

Two questions:

1. Net is larger than gross. Does this bank (the largest in this country) not quite know which is which... or do I miss something?
2. The figures don't sum up. I would expect `net 20.66 = gross 41.18 - tax 20.8`, but it is not. Also, I would expect to have in the end `investment 175,000.00 + net 20.66 = amount 175,020.66`, but the bank will only give me `175,013.73`. How did they get all these figures?

Here are the original data in Spanish copied verbatim from the bank's online system:

```
Instrumento de inversión: PAGARE LIQUIDABLE AL VENCIMIENTO 
Monto de inversión: $175,000.00 
Plazo: 1 Días 
Interés bruto a ganar: $20.66 
Impuesto total: $20.8 
Interés neto a ganar: $41.18 
Importe neto al vencimiento: $ 175,013.73
```

Comment: Just to eliminate one possibility: does "_I cannot understand how **my** bank_" mean you have been dealing with them for some time, and are certain that this is from _their_ website? As opposed, for example, to having only recently being directed to this site from someone offering "an amazing investment opportunity"?

Comment: @TripeHound Yes, I deal with this bank for 23 years. This is the largest bank in the country, and the text is from my personal account in their system, which I have for some 20 years.